# For $f(x) = \frac{(a+x)^b}{a + bx}$, show $f(1) > f(-1)$.

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

Let $f(x) = \frac{(a+x)^b}{a + bx}$ a function of $x$ with parameters $a>1>b>0$.
Show $f(1) > f(-1)$.

This is sort of delicate. For all allowed parameters, $f(x)$ appears to be concave in the range $[-1 , 1]$. Since  $1>b>0$, the numerator is "root-like" which supports   $f(1) > f(-1)$, however due to the denominator characteristics $\frac{1}{a + bx}$ which is falling with $x$, the two effects compete. Moreover, $\lim_{b \to 0} f(x) = \frac{1}{a}$, and  $\lim_{b \to 1} f(x) = 1$, so in these cases $f(1) = f(-1)$ which sets the problematic points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to prove that $\frac{(a+1)^b}{a+b}>\frac{(a-1)^b}{a-b}$ for $a>1>b>0$. This is equivalent to $\frac{a-b}{a+b}>\left(\frac{a-1}{a+1}\right)^b$.

Set $c = a/b$. Then we have $c>a>1$ and $b=a/c$, so the inequality to prove becomes $\frac{a-a/c}{a+a/c}>\left(\frac{a-1}{a+1}\right)^{a/c}$, or equivalently $\left(\frac{c-1}{c+1}\right)^c > \left(\frac{a-1}{a+1}\right)^a$.

So we need to show that $g(x)=\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^x$ is increasing for $x>1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Any comment on the downvote?

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Comment: @jjagmath   Thanks - the rest goes with some derivatives.

Comment: @Andreas If you find my answer useful you could accept it.